# How does pattern matching works using perl

Tags: regex, perl

i have the variables `a:b:c a:b:d c:d:e` and i need the output to be displayed as `a-b a-b c-d`

i try the following code

```
$res="A:B:C A:B:D C:D:E";

$res=~s/\:/\-/g;

$res=~s/..$//mgs;
print "$res\n";
```

But i did not receive output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$res = "A:B:C A:B:D C:D:E";
$res =~ s{([a-z]):([a-z]):[a-z]}{$1-$2}ig;
```

Answer (score 0):

This does as you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $res = "\nA:B:C \nA:B:D \nC:D:E";

my @fields = map { join '-', (split /:/)[0,1] } split ' ', $res;
$res = "@fields\n";

print $res, "\n";
```

**output**

```
A-B A-B C-D
```

Answer (score 0):

Or u can also use `regex match`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $res="A:B:C A:B:D C:D:E";
my @arr = split(/ /,$res);
my $new = "";
for(@arr) {
    /^([a-zA-Z]):([A-Za-z])/;
    $new .= $1."-".$2." ";
}
chop $new;
print $new;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
A-B A-B C-D
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = "A:B:C A:B:D C:D:E";
$res =~ s/(\w):(\w):\w/$1-$2/g;

# $res <-- A-B A-B C-D
```